# Proper way to use ViewModels with Create action in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following in my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Create(int setId)
{
    // create new viewModel
    var model = new CreateCardViewModel() {SetId = setId, Sides = new List<string>(){"Front Side", "Back Side"}};

    return View(model);
}
```

Should I be passing the int to the CreateCardViewModel to construct the model?  Or is this approach appropriate?

Do ViewModels often contain business logic?

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel's don't contain business logic. They're basically a dummy class for outputting to a View.

I wouldn't say that there is a 'proper' way to load a ViewModel, but there are multiple ways you can do this. I personally load any **defaults** for the page in the viewmodel's constructor method, and load any page specific stuff in the controller like you have in your example.

I also use a base viewmodel which is set as the model for the `_layout` page. This holds stuff like your page title/meta stuff/etc.

e.g.

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel
{
    public string Title {get;set;}

}

public sealed class HomeViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public string HomeText {get;set;}
}
```

I dont believe there is a right or wrong way as such, just use techniques which you find comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are useful if you want to ensure that objects are crated in one place. They help avoid situations in which are objects initialized in invalid state (e.g. you forgot to set one of the objects properties, which are required for further processing). In case of view models is good to have constructors for output models. But you cant use constructors for input models (action method's arguments) because they are deserialized by MVC runtime which needs public constructors.